# Добавить ComboBox в DataGridView C#

Tags: c#

Как добавить в существующей столбец `Статус` - `ComboBox`
Был один вариант, но он создает столбец и добавляет `combobox`, а мне нужно на существующий который уже создан
Вот скриншоты и код:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //COMBOBOX
        DataGridViewColumn kol7 = new DataGridViewColumn(); //объявить столбец
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell_CB7 = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell(); //создание ячейки, тип ComboBox

        kol7.HeaderText = "Статус";
        kol7.Name = "column6";
        kol7.Width = 150;

        cell_CB7.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "Первый", "Второй", "Третий", "Четвертый" }); //добавляем в ячейку массив

        kol7.CellTemplate = cell_CB7;  // задаем шаблон

        dgv.Columns.Add(kol7);

    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Он добавляется первым потому что вы не указали куда именно надо добавить comboboх, вы добавляете через Add по умолчанию элемент добавляется в начало столбцов Column[0]

Comment: dataGridView1.Columns[6].Add(cell_CB7) ; если не ошибаюсь, то так вам нужно

Comment: Я прописал то что Вы мне написали - dgv.Columns[6].Add(cell_CB7); ввёл он мне выделяет красным на ошибку в Add